# Como programar 12 luces led secuenciales por cada hora

Tags: python

Quisiera saber como puedo encender 12 luces led con tal que estas se enciendan una por hora hasta completar las 12. Luego al cumplir la hora 13 que se apaguen y quede encendida sólo la primera. La idea es simular un reloj análogo indicando cada hora con un led y que estos se vayan sumando. 
Gracias

Comment: Lee [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y formula nuevamente tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues utilizar la función de fecha para tomar únicamente la hora, con la que validarás así cuantas luces deberán encenderse.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [answer], esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta, saludos

Comment: Hola @anonimo lo pongo así debido a que me es imposible comentar dentro de la pregunta. Agradezco tu comentario.